# simple continuity question

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a question in my text that I don't quite know what to do with:

use the definition of continuity and the properties of limits to show that the function is continuous at the given number a

```
  f(x)=(x + 2x^3)^4,  a=-1
```

so far I have gotten:

```
  (lim x + 2 lim x^3)^4  
   x->a      x->a
```

1. is this correct so far?
2. if so, what is my next move?

Thanks in advance!!!!
(loving this site by the way :-))

Comment: Try to make your question self contained, we do not know what you mean by law 1 and 3 :).

Comment: I imagine one of the laws is just the fact that it's legal to pull a constant in front of the limit. The other is just the fact that you're allowed to add two continuous, smooth functions under one limit and split it into two limits.

Comment: It is clear that $\lim_{x\to -1}x=-1$. The rest is taken care of by your laws, limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, limit of a product is the product of the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, as suggested that the laws you are using, applied to continuous functions, are

- the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits, and
- the limit of the product is the product of the limits (to take care of the "pushing the limit through a power, by considering it as a product limits)

then what you've done is fine.

You simply need to replace $a$ with $-1$ and evaluate the two limits as $x \to -1$, sum them, then take the sum to a power of $4$.

The result will give you $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, given $f(x)$ and given $a = -1$. With that result, you can confirm that indeed, the function is continuous at the given $a$.

Comment: You're welcome!